# Points of inflection for implicit curves

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Here is the graph of `10x^3 + 10x^2 - 10x - 5y^3 + 100y = 5`. How can I find its points of inflection or those parts that the trend of the graph bends or sways?

Reference:

[image: f(x)]

Comment: Do you want to find minimum/maximum of the curve?

Comment: Maybe points where curvature vanishes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
f = 10 x^3 + 10 x^2 - 10 x - 5 y^3 + 100 y - 5;
```

**EDIT:** Simplified calculation of points based on comment by [`mikuszefski`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7608/mikuszefski)

```
(pts1 = {x, y} /. Solve[D[f, y] == 0 && f == 0, {x, y}, Reals] // 
    Simplify) // N

(*  {{-3.08289, 2.58199}, {2.42487, -2.58199}}  *)

(pts2 = {x, y} /. Solve[D[f, x] == 0 && f == 0, {x, y}, Reals] // 
    Simplify) // N

(*  {{-1., -4.44692}, {-1., -0.0500063}, {-1., 
  4.49693}, {0.333333, -4.50601}, {0.333333, 0.0685346}, {0.333333, 
  4.43747}}  *)

Show[
 ContourPlot[f, {x, -8, 8}, {y, -10, 10}, Contours -> {0}, 
  ContourShading -> None],
 Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Red, Point[pts1],
   Blue, Point[pts2]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: @teokan-duran-demircan Hmmm, isn't this answer wrong? Isn't an [inflection point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InflectionPoint.html) a point of vanishing curvature? And why $D[f, x]/D[f, y] == 0$ that's the same as $D[f, x] == 0$ So basically this solution gives the points with horizontal and vertical slope, does it not?

Comment: @mikuszefski - yes calculation of derivatives can be simplified. I leave it to you and OP as to what constitutes "those parts that the trend of the graph bends or sways."

Comment: Sure, OP decides what OP wants. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

I assume an inflection point has zero curvature. Here is my attempt:

```
  eq1 = 10*x^3 + 10*x^2 - 10*x - 5*y^3 + 100*y == 5;
  soln1 = {ToRules[Reduce[eq1, y]]};
  eq2 = FullSimplify[ArcCurvature[{x, y /. soln1[[#]]}, x, "Cartesian"]] == 0 & /@ Range@Length@soln1; (* this may take a while *)
  soln2 = NSolve[#, x, Reals] & /@ eq2  // Flatten[#, 1] &

  pts = {x, y} /. soln1  /. soln2[[#]] & /@ Range@3 // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

> {{-0.343223, -4.4761}, {-0.343223, 0.00794074}, {-0.343223, 
>     4.46816}, {-0.333251, -4.47676}, {-0.333251, 0.00927029}, {-0.333251, 
>     4.46749}, {-0.323341, -4.47742}, {-0.323341, 0.0105916}, {-0.323341,
>      4.46683}}

Inflection points seem to be clustered together.

```
 ContourPlot[Evaluate[eq1], {x, -8, 8}, {y, -10, 10}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[pts]}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should have `pts = ({x, y} /. soln1[[#]] /. soln2[[#]]) & /@ Range@3` (that's why the extra points)

Answer (score 1):

Finding points of vanishing curvature on implicit curve:

```
f[x_, y_] := -5 - 10 x + 10 x^2 + 10 x^3 + 100 y - 5 y^3
h = D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}];
a = D[f[x, y], {{y, x}}] {1, -1};
k[u_, v_] := 
 Expand[a.h.a]/(D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}].D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}])^(3/
      2) /. {x -> u, y -> v}
p = {u, v} /. NSolve[k[u, v] == 0 && f[u, v] == 0, {u, v}, Reals]
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, Contours -> {{0.}}, 
 ContourShading -> None, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[p]}]
```

[image]